# Changing a lowercase character to uppercase in c++

Tags: c++, uppercase, lowercase, toupper

Here is the code that i wrote. When i enter a lowercase character such as 'a', it gives me a blank character but afterwards it works well. Can you tell me what i did wrong? Thanks. :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char letter;

    cout << "You will be asked to enter a character.";
    cout << "\nIf it is a lowercase character, it will be converted to uppercase.";
    cout << "\n\nEnter a character. Press . to stop: ";

    cin >> letter;

    if(islower(letter))
    {
        letter = isupper(letter);
        cout << letter;
    }

    while(letter != '.')
    {
        cout << "\n\nEnter a character. Press . to stop: ";
        cin >> letter;

        if(islower(letter))
        {
            letter = toupper(letter);
            cout << letter;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you print a bool value in the first time.

Comment: What do you expect this to do? `letter = isupper(letter); cout << letter;`. What can `isupper` return, and what does that correspond to in, say , ASCII?

Comment: Can you tell me how i should modify my code please?

Comment: Thanks everybody that's a silly mistake that i did. I thought i modified isupper() to toupper() for both parts. Lol Thanks. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you print a `bool` value (i.e. `false`, aka, [`NUL` character](http://www.asciitable.com/) here) in the first time.

You should change

```
letter = isupper(letter);
```

to

```
letter = toupper(letter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Look here:

```
if(islower(letter))
{
    letter = isupper(letter);
    cout << letter;
}
```

If the character is lower, then you assigned it the return value of `isupper`. That should be 0. So you print a null character.

Why don't you just call `toupper` for every character that you enter? If it's lower it will convert it, if it is already upper it won't do anything.

Comment: Oh wow i didn't think of it that way lol. Thanks to everyone. :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking to convert a lowercase character to an uppercase, you only need to subtract 32 from the lowercase character as this number is the ASCII code difference between uppercase and lowercase characters, e.g., `'a'-'A'=97-67=32`.

```
char c = 'b';
c -= 32; // c is now 'B'
printf("c=%c\n", c);
```

Another easy way would be to first map the lowercase character to an offset within the range of English alphabets `0-25` i.e. 'a' is index '0' and 'z' is index '25' inclusive and then remap it to an uppercase character.

```
char c = 'b';
c = c - 'a' + 'A'; // c is now 'B'
printf("c=%c\n", c);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want you own algorithm:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch = '/0';
    string input("Hello, How Are You ?");
    for(size_t i=0; i<input.length(); i++)
    {
        if(input[i]>=97 && input[i]<=122)
        {
            ch=input[i]-32;
        }
        else
        {
            ch = input[i];
        }
        cout << ch;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `letter = isupper(letter);`, you check whether the variable `letter` is capitalized, to convert it to uppercase you must use the function `toupper()`

```
letter = toupper(letter);
```

Comment: What value does your answer add over the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    string name ;
    cout<<"Lower Case:  ";
    cin>>name;
    int  size_of_string = name.size(); // to detrmine the looping times
    cout<<"Upper case:  ";

    for(int i = 0 ,n = size_of_string ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        //check if the str[i] is lowercase 
        if(name[i]  >= 'a' && name[i]<='z' )
        {
            //convert the Lowercase to uppercase via ASCI Chart
            char a = name[i] - 32 ;
            cout<<a;
        }

        //the user input was upperCase 
        else
        cout<<name[i];
    }

    cout<<"\n Good Bye!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```